How can I use a type parameter as a type parameter in Dart?
The following fails:
class LoaderWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function< Future<T> >() loader;   // Can't use type parameter T as a type parameter
...
}

Function< Future<T> >() ... gives the compile error ...
Expected to find '>'
Is it still not possible in dart to use generic type parameters as type parameters to other types?

When you make a declaration:
void Function<T>() f;

You are declaring that f is a generic function with a type parameter T and that the function takes no arguments and has a void return type.  You can assign only other generic functions to f.  For example:
void g<T>() => print('g<$T>()');

void h() => print('h()');

void main() {
  void Function<T>() f;
  
  f = g;       // OK
  
  f<int>();    // Prints: g<int>()
  f<double>(); // Prints: g<double>()
  
  f = g<int>;  // ERROR
  f = h;       // ERROR
}

Your attempted declaration
final Function< Future<T> >() loader;

does not make sense. Future<T> is not a valid name for a type parameter.  For a generic class, it'd be like the equally nonsensical:
class MyGenericClass<Future<T>> {
  // ...
}

It's not clear what yout intent is.  If you want loader to take a Future<T> argument, then the proper declaration would be:
class LoaderWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(Future<T>) loader;

(Note that the above omits the return type which implicitly means a return type of dynamic.  That's also probably not what you want.)
If you want loader to take no arguments and to return a Future<T>, then the proper declaration would be:
class LoaderWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future<T> Function() loader;

If you do actually want loader to be a generic function, one that takes no arguments, that has a dynamic return type, and that is parameterized on a type derived from Future<T>, then the declaration would be:
class LoaderWidget<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function<U extends Future<T>>() loader;

